# Matrix from a text file

Tags: vb.net, matrix, text-files

Reads a matrix from a text file, the first line of the text file has the dimensions of the matrix, the next lines will contain the elements by rows separated by spaces. I was thinking about using this but don't know how to do the get from text file.

```
   Dim path = "z:matrix.txt"
    Using reader As New IO.StreamReader(path)
        Dim size = reader.ReadLine() ' read first line which is the size of the matrix (assume the matrix is a square)
        Dim A(size - 1, size - 1) As Integer

        Dim j = 0 ' the current line in the matrix
        Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine() ' read next line
        Do While (line <> Nothing) ' loop as long as line is not empty
            Dim numbers = line.Split(" ") ' split the numbers in that line
            For i = 0 To numbers.Length - 1
                A(j, i) = numbers(i) ' copy the numbers into the matrix in current line
            Next

            j += 1 ' increment the current line
            line = reader.ReadLine() ' read next line
            Console.WriteLine(line)
        Loop


    End Using
```

3

1 3 5

2 4 6

7 8 9

Comment: Do you have more than one matrix in that text file? If you have, the code required is slightly more complex, if you haven't, the first value is useless. So, are the matrix values always separated by a line feed (or is it more than one line feed, as it looks like, given the sample you posted?), or could they be presented in a single line (which would make the first value - the dimension - meaningful)?

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim path = "D:\matrix.txt"
Using reader As New IO.StreamReader(path)
    Dim size = reader.ReadLine() ' read first line which is the size of the matrix (assume the matrix is a square)
    Dim A(size - 1, size - 1) As Integer

    Dim j = 0 ' the current line in the matrix
    Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine() ' read next line
    Do While (line <> Nothing) ' loop as long as line is not empty
        Dim numbers = line.Split(" ") ' split the numbers in that line
        For i = 0 To numbers.Length - 1
            A(j, i) = numbers(i) ' copy the numbers into the matrix in current line
        Next

        j += 1 ' increment the current line
        line = reader.ReadLine() ' read next line
    Loop

    A.Dump() ' print the matrix in LinqPad
End Using
```

Text file sample:

```
3
1 3 5
2 4 6
7 8 9
```

Result in LinqPad.
[image]

Modified code without LinqPad:

```
Dim path = "d:\matrix.txt"
Dim A(,) As Integer
Using reader As New IO.StreamReader(path)
    Dim size = reader.ReadLine() ' read first line which is the size of the matrix (assume the matrix is a square)
    Redim A(size - 1, size - 1)

    Dim j = 0 ' the current line in the matrix
    Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine() ' read next line
    Do While (line <> Nothing) ' loop as long as line is not empty
        Dim numbers = line.Split(" ") ' split the numbers in that line
        For i = 0 To numbers.Length - 1
            A(j, i) = numbers(i) ' copy the numbers into the matrix in current line
        Next

        j += 1 ' increment the current line
        line = reader.ReadLine() ' read next line
    Loop
End Using

Console.WriteLine("Matrix A :")
Dim numberWidth As Integer = 2
Dim format As String = "D" & numberWidth
For i As Integer = 0 To A.GetUpperBound(0)
    Console.Write("| ")
    For j As Integer = 0 To A.GetUpperBound(1)
        Console.Write("{0} ", A(i, j).ToString(format))
    Next
    Console.WriteLine("|")
Next
```

Comment: Hello, i am new to this, is possible if you could write in code for VB, don't know what linqpad is sorry

Comment: Just copy the code and paste it in a console app. Remove the A.Dump() line. Use loop to print the numbers into the console. Don't forget to create a text file and modify the path variable.

Comment: I done it but not getting the first line, posed the code, please let me know

Comment: Post your text file and the code you wrote based on mine.

Comment: You printed the line AFTER reading the next line. Print the line before reading the next line. But if you want to be sure, print the matrix instead of the lines. I modified my code to use your print matrix code.

Comment: thank you, is their a way which the user can write the matrix into the text file before hand, like the method used for the first matrix asks user for first row,first column etc would their be a away to write into file after specifying the dimension

Comment: yes, like before the reading section user has ability to write the code into a text file, same layout as your original text file

Comment: I suggest you read about how to read/write textfiles. Then change the read a line part into write a line.

Comment: i know how to write files, i've done another more similar task to see, however for this one i can not for some reason. I do not know how to skip the lines due to the next line etc, could you please help me